# How can I get a CGImageRef from a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I know you can get a `CGImage` from a file using UIImage...

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name.bmp"];
[img CGImage];
```

But, is there a way to get a `CGImageRef` without using a `UIImage`?

(I am trying this in a static library which doesn't have access to UIKit) I could use other frameworks if necessary, just not UIKit. Would `CIImage` work? Or `NSBitmapImageRep`?

Comment: ImageIO.framework will be available, but otherwise you can't read a BMP simply by pure CG functions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the harm in loading the image from UIImage? Is there a significant memory difference?

Comment: I am doing this in a unit test. Our static lib that we are writing takes in a CGImageRef. I want to test it by passing one in from a test file I have. I tried loading UIKit in my unit test project, and doing the UIImage way, but it never worked. I assume it is because my unit test project is not a view application

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get it from NSData:

```
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@""]);
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); // Or JPEGDataProvider
```

You would have to be certain that the data was a JPEG or a PNG for this to work.

Comment: sweet! Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to do this for a BMP? There's no CGImageCreateWithBMPDataProvider...

Comment: No, sorry, I think you'll have to go through the UIImage route for that :(

Comment: This really helped me out, but you should know, that you have to release the memory that holds the `CGImageRef` with the following `CGImageRelease(image);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that using [UIImage imageNamed:@"name.bmp"] works through UIKit framework. This is not thread safe. Example for dispatch_apply you must use Quartz framework.

```
// Through Quartz
NSString *maskFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mask" ofType:@"png"];
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([maskFilePath UTF8String]);
CGImageRef maskRef = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Comment: Apple's current developer documentation describes UIImage objects as "safe to create and use from any thread".  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage